# Downloading a lot of images with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a large list of URLs (8000+) I want to download the images from.
I created a script that will download the files, as long as I'm setting the limit to about a 100.
If I try to download more I'm getting errors like

> - (node:6740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: read ECONNRESET
> - (node:3808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
> - (node:7052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

This is the code that reads my CSV with URL's:

```
const fotoDownload = require('./async-foto');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('\\\\hk-nas02\\import\\Partij\\Files\\partij.csv')
    .pipe(csv( { separator: ';'}))
    .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log(results.length)

        let NoPartijen = results.length;
                
        for(i = 0;i < 50; i++){
            //console.log(results[i]);
            itemno = i
            path = '..\\files\\images\\'+results[i]['partij.VPARTIJNR']+'_'+results[i]['partij.PARTIJNR']+'_H.jpg';
            console.log(path)
            
            fotoDownload.fotoDownload(results[i]['partij.EXFOTOURL'], path, itemno)
            
        }

        console.log('Test');
    });
```

and calls the following code to download:

```
const util = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')
const axios = require("axios").default;


module.exports = {
    fotoDownload: async (url, path, itemno) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios({
                method: "GET",
                url: url,
                responseType: "stream",})
            
            await response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
            console.log('Start foto download' + itemno);
            return;
            } catch (err) {
                throw new Error(err)
            }
        
    }
}
```

I'm assuming I need the chop the data into chunks or something, but I'm a bit lost here. Can someone put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a timeout for downloading the images & add connection keep-alive

something like this

```
axios.defaults.timeout = 30000; //or whateve your desired timeout
axios.defaults.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
module.exports = {
    fotoDownload: async (url, path, itemno) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios({
                method: "GET",
                url: url,
                responseType: "stream",})
            
            await response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
            console.log('Start foto download' + itemno);
            return;
            } catch (err) {
                throw new Error(err)
            }
        
    }
}
```

Note: make sure u have https installed
run `npm i http or npm i https`